# Show image in div and add PREV/NEXT buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I create kind of gallery in Wordpress. However, posts are listed with plugin (they are attached to map - WP Google Map) and I can't use any gallery plugin. I just upload images and want to add them to div "showimagediv". This works fine but I can't make PREV/NEXT.

This is what it looks like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumb').on('click', function() {
    var img = $('<img />', {
      src: this.src,
      'class': 'fullImage'
    });
    $('.showimagediv').html(img).show();
  });

  $('.showimagediv').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post_content">
  <img src="image1.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <img src="image2.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <img src="image3.jpg" class="thumb" />
</div>
<div class="post_content">
  <img src="image4.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <img src="image5.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <img src="image6.jpg" class="thumb" />
</div>
<div class="post_content">
  <img src="image7.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <img src="image8.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <img src="image9.jpg" class="thumb" />
</div>
```

It works well but doesn't give me option to to PREV/NEXT.

Comment: are you using any lightbox or similar to show the image, or are you just CSSing the image bigger?

Comment: I use the script above to load the picture with bigger class into the "showimagediv"

Comment: I guess you need to create your own "nextSelector" then - and some custom jQuery to switch to the next image

Comment: But how can I load all pictures from div to "showimagediv" to use PREV/NEXT? Or how can I make the script load next image when click NEXT?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested - but might help you get the idea.

HTML

```
<div class="nextSelector">
    <span>NEXT</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.nextSelector').on('click',function(){
    var nextImage = $('img.fullImage + img');
    $('img.fullImage').toggleClass("thumb fullImage");
    nextImage.toggleClass("thumb fullImage");
})
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is I add the class but also load the image into div. But what you wrote could be a solution without loading it into next div, but displaying big image

Comment: And a question. Will it definitely add the class to next div in "post_content"? Not to any other in page that something collapses?

Comment: this should add the fullImage to the next image in the same post_content - but it will not go to the next post_content